# How to compare two hashmaps based on keys and if the values are mismatched I need print the mismatch key and values

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I will explain the scenario, I have two hash maps lets take

```
Map<String,String> map_A = new HashMap<>(); 

mapA.put("Name", "Jerry");
mapA.put("State", "Texas");

Map<String,String> map_B = new HashMap<>();

mapB.put("Name","TOM");
mapB.put("State", "Texas");
```

My keys will be same in all cases.

Expected output :

> Name Jerry TOM mismatched

I need to print only in case if there is a mismatch.

Comment: Do you have a question?  If you have tried this and are having trouble getting it to work, please post what you tried.  If you haven't tried it, please try first.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of attempt / prior research. This is really basic stuff, and there are zillions of examples for such things. Beyond that : read about raw types - and then stop using them. You should put type information on the left hand side of your map declarations!

Comment: what's the problem ? Get the values on key basis compare the values if not equal then print the keys.

Comment: @Lokesh I need to compare both the maps ... keys will be same if the values are mismatching i need to display in console

Comment: @PrishiKumar check the answer

Comment: @PrishiKumar I have updated the answer according to your needs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on the keys will be same and display the key for different values you can try some thing like this

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("Name", "Jerry");
        map1.put("State", "Texas");
        map2.put("Name","TOM");
        map2.put("State", "Texas");
        Iterator<?> it = map1.entrySet().iterator();
        Iterator<?> it1 = map2.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext() && it1.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            Map.Entry pair1 = (Map.Entry)it1.next();
            if(!pair.getValue().equals(pair1.getValue())) {
                System.out.println(pair.getKey()+" "+pair.getValue()+" "+pair1.getValue()+" mismatched");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Name Jerry TOM mismatched
```

Comment: @PrishiKumar is the comparison based on the same criteria ? By the way this code is working absolutely fine i already tested it on my pc

Comment: it show mismatch for few fields even if it is matching . .

Comment: column names  I have taken as keys, column values as values..two tables of same structure

Comment: @PrishiKumar I saw there was a mistake can you check it now ? It should work absolutely fine now

Comment: Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> this is correct right ?

Comment: No you need to declare one variable like this `Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> map1;`

Comment: So my maps must be declared like this ?

Comment: Can you update your post and include your latest code. Please raise a different question but before that read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Thanks Lokesh, I think I have some problem while declaring the maps

Comment: I am not saying that your map should be declare like that. your iterator should be declare like that

Comment: welcome and please consider accepting the solution in case if i helped you in any way.

Comment: @PrishiKumar what's up with down vote ? Is that yours ?

Comment: Nope  . . Your answer has helped me out why should I down vote it .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String,String> mapA = new HashMap<>();
    mapA.put("Name", "Jerry");
    mapA.put("State", "Texas");
    Map<String,String> mapB = new HashMap<>();
    mapB.put("Name","TOM");
    mapB.put("State", "Texas");
    Set<String> bKeys = mapB.keySet();
    mapA.keySet().stream()
            .filter(bKeys::contains)
            .distinct()
            .map(key -> {
                String valA = mapA.get(key);
                String valB = mapB.get(key);
                if (Objects.equals(valA, valB)) {
                    return null;
                }
                return key + " " + valA + " vs " + valB + " mismatched";
            })
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: @PrishiKumar read about streams https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm

Comment: Thanks yegor, but this checks only the first pair

Comment: No, it's itarate for all keys of mapA and MapB and gets distinct key values. After that we checks that values in map are not equals and creates the string with diff

Comment: The problem is when I use this method, map 1 data is coming correctly from database but for map2 values I am getting values which are not in database. when I tried displaying the key and value is coming correctly, few values are coming as null for map 2.. and how I can call this from main method ?

Comment: @PrishiKumar i have edited my answer for your last comment